# How to make a node that would contain a list as well

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I searched a lot to find useful content over this topic but invain. I have made a linked list that is working fine. Now, as an assigment, I am required to store some dictionary words given in a file "input.txt". It is mentioned that you have to do this assignment using 2-D linked lists i.e., making another linked list inside the node of the linked list. Which means every node of the linked list would now contain a list as well. This can aslo be done with vectors but I guess linked list might be more helpful.
Now Consider the code.

//In list.h

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;
    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
        this->value = theVal;
        this->next = NULL;
        this->prev = NULL;
    }
};

template <class T>
class List
{
    ListItem<T> *head;

public:

    // Constructor
    List();

    // Destructor
    ~List();
}
```

I need to make a linked list inside the node So in "Struct ListItem" I am doing something like this:

```
List<T> dictionary;
```

But it is giving an error:

```
"ISO C++ forbids declaration of âListâ with no type"
```

Second, how would I start making another linked list inside the node. I mean suppose temp pointer points to head of the first linked list. How would I now make another node (that would belong to my 2nd linked list) inside this node. I guess may be by something like this:

```
temp->ListItem<T>* secondListNode = new ListItem<T>(item); // I don't know whether
//It would or not as I am stuck in the first part.
```

This has to be done using 2-D format so please just stick to the constraints. Any other Useful suggestion regarding this problem would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that doing this with a linked list would be "more helpful"? Linked lists are a horrible data structure, and are virtually only ever used in school assignments.

Comment: So  how would I make a vector inside a node???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular dependency. If you only have a pointer to `ListItem<T>` in `List<T>`, then declare `ListItem<T>` first, then define `List<T>` and after that define the `ListItem<T>` class:

```
template<class T>
class ListItem;

template<class T>
class List
{
    ListItem<T> *head;

    // ...
};

template<class T>
class ListItem
{
    // `dictionary` is not a pointer or a reference,
    // so need the full definition of the `List<T>` class
    List<T> dictionary;

    // ...
};
```

Comment: @DeadCoder What error? The code as posted in my answer compiles fine.

Comment: @Joachmin It is still giving the same error as mentioned above. "forbids List of no type." If you define List<string> dict inside struct ListItem.

Comment: @DeadCoder Please edit your question to contain the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message(s), and also how use the list classes.

Comment: @Joachmin I get what you said there. Just one more thing, Now that you have a list inside a node. how would you make/declare its head. Can you explain it a bit. My pointer to node of first link would now point to node of second list or what. I am totally blank over this.

Answer (score 0):

As you refer to a dictionary, you may think about using a std::map instead.

for example:

```
std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string> >
```

if you are storing your values as std::string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean with "Which means every node of the linked list would now contain a list *as well.*"

If you just want to have a *list of lists of strings*, you can easily instantiate this with your existing List data structure, thanks to the template feature:

```
List<List<std::string> > listOfLists;
```

Of course, you can still have your "1D-list" too:

```
List<std::string> otherList;
```

Normally, it's a bad idea to adapt data structures to local requirements, but instead try to use generic data structures in a more specialized way, like above the "list of lists". Do not implement a "list of lists" as a separate class, nor change your generic list to a 2D-list. It's just a "list of any type `T`", so `T` can also be a list again (and again, and again...).

Comment: Do you think it would be much easier If i each node contains a vector instead of a list ????

Comment: The generic node shouldn't contain some other data structure. You design a generic data structure `List<T>`. *Then* you instantiate it with a specific `T` which can for example be a `List<std::string>` or `std::vector<std::string>`. There is a difference between "list of lists" (my approach) and "list in which a node has a list" (your approach).

Comment: If you want to map from a string to a list of strings (as I understand a "dictionary") you should make a class which holds the string (key) and a list of strings (values), let's call it `DictEntry`. Then, use this class as the item type for your list: `List<DictEntry> dictionary`. Don't touch your implementation of `List<T>`, that's wrong!